# I have a bunch of strings, how do I make them into a list without having a list of individual words?

Tags: python

```
s = ('hi my name is, huh', '    ', '', 'my name is, what', 'my name is harry potter')
and turn it into:

l = ['hi my name is, huh', '    ', '', 'my name is, what', 'my name is harry potter']
```

I have a bunch of strings, how do I make them into a list without having a list of individual words?

Comment: You have declared your s as a tuple ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `list`.

```
>>> s = ('hi my name is, huh', '    ', '', 'my name is, what', 'my name is harry potter')
>>> list(s)
['hi my name is, huh', '    ', '', 'my name is, what', 'my name is harry potter']
```